# Loop Never Ends in Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

Basically, I have below assembly code:

```
global _start
section .bss
    input:  resq 100
section .data
    buf: db "Input> ",  7
    pas: db "password", 8
section .text
_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ecx, buf
    mov edx, 7
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 100
    int 0x80
    mov cx, 50
Loop:
    dec cx
    mov eax, 4
    mov ecx, pas
    mov edx, 8
    int 0x80

    jnz Loop
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

I am trying to loop through 0-50 and print the variable `pas` or probably `buf` from input box. But this loop keeps printing `pas` endlessly. I Presume the issue is the re-assignment of `ecx`, but otherwise without putting my string into `ecx` how would I print it? or even execute any thing within my loop at all?

Arc: `Linux kali 5.2.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.2.9-2kali1 (2019-08-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: You need to save and reload your counter, e.g. by `push`/`pop`. Or use a different, free register, e.g. `esi`. Also you should put the `dec` before the `jnz` to avoid trouble.

Comment: @Jester, can you update my code and add using `push/pop`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption by overwriting `ecx` was correct, fixed it by using `push & pop` as below:

Credit goes to @Jester.

```
global _start
section .bss
    input:  resq 100
section .data
    buf: db "Input> ",  7
    pas: db "password", 8
section .text
_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ecx, buf
    mov edx, 7
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 100
    int 0x80
    xor cx, cx

Loop:
    inc cx
    push cx
    mov eax, 4
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 8
    int 0x80

    pop cx
    cmp cx, 5
    jne Loop

    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```